# Excel formula to sort a row and return sorted values in adjacent cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of alphanumerical values in multiple rows. For e.g

```
 a1          b1        c2     
 b1          a2        d3     
 c1          a2        d3
```

I want to sort values is Row 1, Row 2 and Row 3 individually into adjacent cells. For. eg

```
 a1          b1        c2     =>       a1          b1        c2       
 b1          a2        d3     =>       a2          b1        d3
 c1          a2        d3     =>       a2          c1        d3
```

I can do it for two rows, but for more than two rows it became complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively easy to do with VBA and a User Defined Function.  Since there are only a few items to sort, I used a simple BubbleSort.  Other methods could be used also.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=sortAlpha(A1:C1)
```

in a range of cells extending across your destination (eg: E1:G1) and then fill down.

This is an **array formula** and will return an array of values.  So to enter it you would, for example:

- First select E1:G1
- Then put your cursor in the formula bar and enter the formula
- Finally, instead of just hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>, you must hold down <kbd>ctrl + shift</kbd> while you hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces  **{...}** around the formula

---

```
Option Explicit

'Comment out next line for case sensitive sorting
Option Compare Text

Function sortAlpha(rg As Range) As String()
    Dim S() As String
    Dim C As Range
    Dim I As Long

ReDim S(0 To rg.Count - 1)
For Each C In rg
    S(I) = C.Text
    I = I + 1
Next C

SingleBubbleSort S

sortAlpha = S

End Function
Sub SingleBubbleSort(TempArray As Variant)
'copied directly from support.microsoft.com
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim NoExchanges As Integer

    ' Loop until no more "exchanges" are made.
    Do
        NoExchanges = True

        ' Loop through each element in the array.
        For I = LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray) - 1

            ' If the element is greater than the element
            ' following it, exchange the two elements.
            If TempArray(I) > TempArray(I + 1) Then
                NoExchanges = False
                Temp = TempArray(I)
                TempArray(I) = TempArray(I + 1)
                TempArray(I + 1) = Temp
            End If
        Next I
    Loop While Not (NoExchanges)
End Sub
```

---

[image]